# Intellisense not working in Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, intellisense

I don't know if the correct term is intellisense, I'm talking about the helpers you see when you place the mouse over something. (The /** *** */ helpers)

For some particular (business) reasons I need to use Flash Builder 4.0, the problem is, all kin of intellisense is gone, I put my mouse over anything, and no intellisense appears, nor in basic AS3 methods (Math.function) nor in Flex ones.

Any ideas?, I've been using FB 4.6 for a long time, and I never had this problem before.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

it worked in FB4.0 as well, so either it can be an installation problem, or the SDK the project points to doesn't contain the documentation. Try a new project, see if there works. If not, try reinstalling it with default settings, and see if it works.

Comment: Tried a new project, same problem. I forgot to say, I'm using an old SDK, the 3.0.1 version. Could it be that some sdks don't have intellisense available or something like that?.